# How to use char pointers in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a BF clone, and this is what I have so far, but it throws me a error. Anyone knows how to use char pointers?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char* ptr1;
    ++ptr1;
    putchar(*ptr1);
}
```

Comment: What error would help in your question. However, answer one of mine: What does `ptr1` point to? As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What's a BF clone?

Answer (score 2):

This code has Undefined Behaviour.

`char* ptr1;` declares a uninitialised pointer to a `char`. It doesn't point to anything and has indeterminate value. Reading it is UB.

`++ptr1;` increments the (garbage) value of the pointer by one. This is where you hit UB, and even if it wasn't UB, what do you expect that to accomplish?

`putchar(*ptr1);` tries to print the `char` pointed to by `ptr1`, but since it doesn't point to anything, this has no well defined behaviour either.

In short, the program is simply invalid and the compiler is allowed to do *anything* to it. You cannot have *any* expectations as to the result.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using such notations in C after all it's C++.

Btw you need to read about `putchar()` here: [cplusplus.com reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putchar/).

`Issues`

You are trying to increment a char pointer which is undefined and top of it you are invalidating `putchar()`, whose syntax is

> int putchar ( int character );

It should be something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ptr1= 'c';
    putchar(ptr1);
}
```

Comment: Mentioned both . -:)

Comment: The point is that `++ptr1;` and `*ptr1` each already have undefined behavior.

Comment: Defining `*ptr1` is fine. It has nothing to do with undefined behavior. The problem arises when he did `++ptr1`.

Comment: @uneven_mark I just said "Defining the `ptr1` is fine.". I didn't said de-referencing is ok.

Comment: I misread, sorry. I still think that talking about `putchar` is somehow besides the point.

Comment: Oh come on, I really want to do this BF clone! Should I give up?

Comment: @NabeGameDev What's that ? Give some idea . May be we can help .

Comment: @Problematic It's a esorectic programming language made by Urban Muller, and the language's goal is to create the smallest compiler possible. It is known for being hard to code in.